# Is there a way to, find and replace the text value between nodes of a corrupt xml file, using libxml?

Tags: c, libxml2

libxml, info. needed without actually parsing the file.

Is there a way to, find and replace the text value between nodes of a corrupt xml file, using libxml?

Answer (score 0):

I know libxml via PHP, so I'm not sure this works for you: Use loadHTMLFile instead of load. This way even a corrupted file can be loaded, if it's not more corrupted than usual websites ;-)
Once loaded, you can handle it like any normal XML. If you save it, the file will be repaired.
If this does not work, the file has heavy damages. Then there is no way to access the file with libxml.

Comment: the file has <test> new val & </test>  the occurence of & is to be replaced by a space to make the file a good xml, if this replacement is not done the file would give a parsing error with the call to xmlParseFile(). Andreas, I am trying to find a clean and fast way of doing this replacement.

Comment: As far as I see, unescaped occurences of the ampersand character "&" can not be handled with libxml. It also can't be defined as entity in a DTD (I tried this to be sure). It looks like you have to run an old fashioned search & replace, e.g. with regex. If your example does always fit, search for " & " (blank, ampersand, blank) to avoid damaging other data.

Answer (score 0):

In general - no. It depends on how the file is corrupted. Please clarify it.

Comment: the file has <test> new val & </test>  the occurence of & is to be replaced by a space to make the file a good xml, if this replacement is not done the file would give a parsing error with the call to xmlParseFile(). Oleg, I am trying to find a clean and fast way of doing this replacement.